# Python: No sé cómo revisar más de un registro de un diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios

El ejercicio es el siguiente:

Crear un programa que dado un nombre de usuario y una contraseña, compruebe los datos de acceso de un usuario.

El programa solicitará el nombre de usuario y contraseña, después mostrará un mensaje por la salida estándar en función de las siguientes indicaciones:

El usuario indicado no existe. → Error 70

El usuario indicado existe, pero la contraseña no le corresponde. → Error 72

El usuario indicado existe y la contraseña indica le corresponde. → Error 74

Tengo un código que te pone el contenido del archivo "usuarios.txt" en un diccionario (el archivo va por columnas usuario contraseña) y te verifica si el usuario que le has añadido está dentro del diccionario.

El problema está en el hecho de que solamente de verífica si el usuario está en el primer "registro" del diccionario. Si está en el segundo, te dice que no existe.

Aquí está el código:

```
import hashlib

usuari = input("Escriu el nom del usuari: ")

contrasenya = input("Escriu la contrasenya: ")

contrasenya = hashlib.sha512( str(contrasenya).encode("utf-8") ).hexdigest()

d = {}
with open("usuaris.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[key] = val
#print(d)

for clave in d:
  # Obtener el valor referido por clave
  valor = d[clave] # <-- Así es que debería usarse un d
                             #    ¿Por qué es que estás revisando término a
  print(usuari)
  print(clave)
  print(contrasenya)
  print(valor)                           #     término el d? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  # Hacer algo con ese valor
  if usuari == clave:
    if contrasenya == valor:
        print("cont cor")
        break
    else:
        print("Contrasenya inc")
        break
  else:
    print("usu inc")
    break
```

(Las variables están escritas en catalán)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te falla es que no sabes usar un diccionario: si tienes la llave (la cuenta de usuario en este caso), no necesitas *buscar*; simplemente **accesas** usando `d[usuari]`.

El código corregido es:

```
if usuari in d:
    valor = d[usuari] # <-- Así es que debería usarse un d
                             #    ¿Por qué es que estás revisando término a
    # Hacer algo con ese valor
    if contrasenya == valor:
        print("cont cor")
    else:
        print("Contrasenya inc")
else:
    print("usu inc")
```

Lo primero es preguntar si `usuari` está en el diccionario `d`. Si lo está, es un usuario registrado, y `d[usuari]` me da la password registrada.

Teniendo la password registrada y la ingresada, sólo tengo que compararlas por igualdad.

Si el usuario no está registrado, simplemente imprimo un mensaje.

No hay necesidad de hacer ningun ciclo.

#### Demo

*usuarios.txt*

```
luis luis
raul zaskaui
sergio a9344
```

*código*

```
usuari = "raul"
contrasenya = "zaskaui"

d = {}
with open("usuarios.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[key] = val
#print(d)

if usuari in d:
    valor = d[usuari] 
    if contrasenya == valor:
        print("cont cor")
    else:
        print("Contrasenya inc")
else:
    print("usu inc")
```

produce:

```
cont cor

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Nota: Me salte la parte de calcular el hash para no complicarme creando el caso de prueba (debería estar incluido en la pregunta) y calcular los hash.